# TypeError: object() takes no parameters when trying to admin.site.register

Tags: python, django

all of other models registered sucsessfully the same way, exept one:

trying to `admin.site.register(ProductImage, ProductImageAdmin)`

`in products/models.py`:

```
class ProductImage(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='product_images/')
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return ('Phpoto %s' % (self.id))

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'photo'
```

in products/admin.py:

```
class ProductImageAdmin:
    list_display = [field.name for field in ProductImage._meta.fields]
    exclude = []

    class Meta:
        model = ProductImage
```

error is:

> File "C:\Dev\tst\products\admin.py", line 22, in 
>       admin.site.register(ProductImage, ProductImageAdmin)
>     File "C:\Users\Anti-\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 124, in re
>   gister
>       self._registry[model] = admin_class(model, self)
>   TypeError: object() takes no parameters

is that something special for ImageField?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you forgot to `inherit` from `admin.ModelAdmin`, [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-objects)

```
from django.contrib import admin
class ProductImageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
```